# Как удалить группы строк по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','огурец','вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша','арбуз','груша','банан', 'груша', 'вишня','яблоко', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', 'россия','россия', 'франция','ЮАР','франция', 'россия', np.nan,'россия','андорра', 'франция', 'португалия', 'россия', np.nan, 'россия'],
'id': ['01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['март','январь','январь','март', 'сентябрь','март','октябрь', 'март', 'ноябрь', 'январь','январь', 'март', 'январь', 'январь', 'ПРОПУЩЕНО', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно удалить строки с id (предварительно проведя группировку по id), где значения месяца идут последовательно со значениями, где:

1. март
2. октябрь \ ноябрь
3. январь

Или со значениями , где:

1. март
2. январь

На первом рисунке зачеркнуты строки, которые нужно удалять. В общем случае в группе id может быть бесконечное число строк, важно при наличии описанной последовательности

Как это можно сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: непонятно почему удалена третья группа - ведь в ней нет января в конце?

Comment: @Jack_oS Здравствуйте, это не учебные задания, а придуманные мной самостоятельно, чтобы разобраться с рабочей ситуацией. В данном случае мне неизвестно с какой стороны подходить к этой задаче в связи с отсутствием сильных навыков в pandas

Comment: @MaxU это опечатка моя, извините)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
patterns = [["март", "январь"], ["март","октябрь", "январь"], ["март", "ноябрь", "январь"]]

res = df.groupby("id").filter(lambda x: x["месяц"].unique().tolist() not in patterns)
```

результат:

```
In [134]: res
Out[134]:
      фрукт   страна  id      месяц
3   абрикос   россия  02       март
4     груша  франция  02   сентябрь
5     арбуз      ЮАР  03       март
6     груша  франция  03    октябрь
13  абрикос   россия   5     январь
14    груша      NaN   5  ПРОПУЩЕНО
15    банан   россия   5     апрель
```